# My installed WPF app is crashing while trying to create a file

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, release, setup-deployment

I have a problem with my WPF application (a simple clicker game). I've just made a deployment/created a setup project using Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects extension for Visual Studio. Everything seemed to work fine, setup works good (tested on other computer) and furthermore the installed application almost works correctly. The only exception is a button calling function which is creating a new txt (something like a draft of a "save" file) file in a folder where the application is installed. Clicking this button cause instant crash of the whole application. Nothing else happens, no error message, the app just turns off.

I assume that the problem lies in access rights to the folder/administrator rights.

I've added txt file with the same name in the application folder using "File System" window in setup project, deployed and installed again. Even when the file exists the problem happend again (probably because of access rights when trying to override file content).

It's may be important that everything worked while running app through VS, also using .exe works fine on any computer. The problem is only with application installed using setup.

I'm not sure where the problem is so it's hard to show some code, to be honest i'm not even sure if it's a problem with code, maybe it can be solved with setting some setup project properties?

I would like to store some data locally between two sessions, i've choosed txt file because it's light and simple even if it's not the most elegant way. 
I expect that installed application will be able to create and override txt file in it's folder.

P.S. if you need any code, screenshots or information about my setup please let me know in comments section, I will provide what's necessary

Comment: As I said, while running with VS everything is fine. The problem occurs only when application is deployed

Comment: Where are you saving the file? Can you post the code that saves the txt file? Also  you can put some exception handling around the code you think is causing the problem, and in the catch you can generate a message dialog that displays the error message.  Might give you a better idea of whats going on.

Comment: will need to have a look at the code to see how you construct the file path. An installed application will reside in "Program Files" folder and it's likely you do not have access right to it. You might want to consider storing such data in the ApplicationData folder. Read this for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659127/folder-to-store-data-files-locally-in-wpf-application

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30915.c-local-files.aspx You can "install" an app just by copying the contents of bin/Release to some folder. If this is just something you're experimenting with then your simplest option might be just to copy your exe and dll into a folder in My Games

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you install your program you're having administrator-rights. So the folder where your application is, also was created with administrator-rigths.

If you want to store data to this folder, you'll have to run your application as administrator. (not the best idea)

Otherwise you can change your code to write your file at runtime to a different location where you don't need administrator-rights.

For example:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
```

will give you: "C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local"

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

will give you: "C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming"

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

will give you: "C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents"

And some error-handling around the saving of the file would be very nice and helpful ;)

Comment: You are right, thank you. 
Error message returned simply "access to the path denied", as I assumed.
Your solution works for me, it was caused by my luck of knowledge about special folders access rights.
Thank you for your knowledge and solution!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for solution and knowledge, the problem was as I assumed (access to the path denied).
I was using this code to create a path:

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\SyntyhCitySave.txt";
```

Creating a file in a special directory instead of application folder works, that's the solution for my problem:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + "\\SyntyhCitySave.txt";
```

Tomtom answer marked as accepted.